# Wrapfig floating to bottom (Article)

Tags: wrap

I'm trying to get a figure to float beside text but I keep getting the error "wrapfigure used inside conflicting environment," and the figure floats down to the bottom. I'm pretty sure it's not in a list unless sections count as a list, and I've tried commenting out just about everything to see what's conflicting and I can't find it.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}


\begin{document}
\section{Task Management Structure}
\begin{flushleft}
In order to efficiently utilize JIRA for task management, the general structure of
site’s components must be understood. This section discusses JIRA's structure and how
it will be used.
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.85\textwidth]{JIRATaskManagementStructure}
\end{center}

\section{Navigating Dashboard}

\subsection{Introduction}


\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{image}
\end{wrapfigure}

The \emph{Introduction} section provides a link to the
\texttt{\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com}{Valid Link}}. 

\subsection{Introduction2}


\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{image2}
\end{wrapfigure}
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

The first graphic works, but it isn't a wrapfig, so I don't think it matters to what's happening. I've been looking through stuff for about an hour and not finding anything that helps. The second wrapfig takes in the image from the first.

Comment: Check the documentation. I'm pretty sure that's too near to a section break. `wrapfig` is extremely particular. You're lucky - at least your figure appears somewhere! Mine tend to just disappear. ;) Remember that you need to make sure there is enough text in the paragraphs. You've got one quite short sentence which is likely nowhere near enough for the height of the graphic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by minipages.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\subsection{Introduction}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
The \emph{Introduction} section provides a link to the 
\texttt{\href{https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA061/JIRA+User
\%27s+Guide}{JIRA User's Guide}}. 
Anytime you need additional assistance, please check the User's Guide for more help. 
As it is extensive, please expect a small load time.
\end{minipage}

\hspace{.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{JIRAIntro.png}
\label{fig:figure1}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is MWE of wraping figure.[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\section{Task Management Structure}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{.5\textwidth}

\centering

\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{sbplogo}

\caption{State Bank of Pakistan}

\end{wrapfigure}

In order to efficiently utilize JIRA for task management, the general structure of
site’s components must be understood. This section discusses JIRA's structure and how
it will be used.In order to efficiently utilize JIRA for task management, the general structure of
site’s components must be understood. This section discusses JIRA's structure and how
it will be used.In order to efficiently utilize JIRA for task management, the general structure of
site’s components must be understood. This section discusses JIRA's structure and how
it will be used.In order to efficiently utilize JIRA for task management, the general structure of
site’s components must be understood. This section discusses JIRA's structure and how
it will be used.


\end{document}
```